# where to look in the cloudshell (Google App Engine) for deployed app files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am deploying a simple Flask app with `gcloud` from my terminal, and I would like to simply look at the files (`app.yaml`, `main.py`, `requirements.txt`) in Cloud Shell but they are nowhere to be found.

I have even tried:

```
find -name main.py -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n
find -name app.yaml -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n
find -name requirements.txt -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n
```

which looks for the file and sorts in order of date modified, but these files do not show up despite the app being successfully deployed, and I am certain that I am in the correct Cloud Shell for the project.

I'm starting to think I can't interact with the files of a deployed app in Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm starting to think I can't interact with the files of a deployed app in Cloud Shell?

Correct, the environment you deploy to for App Engine is not the same as the environment you get for Cloud Shell. Cloud Shell is a persistent VM that you can do whatever you'd like in. The App Engine runtime is a restricted runtime that is updated from scratch every time you make a new deployment.